# Suspension and cones in topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm studying math by myself and I always have troubles with topology. The thing is all the authors of textbooks never give details of reasoning of such kind of stuff like "this thing glued with this thing gives us this thing", ever. Authors always say that, fr instance, cell with its boundary glued into a single point  gives a sphere and I can easily imagine why (in 2-d case), but I don't know how to prove it and I never saw the proof of things like that.

Could someone explain a details of proof, say, that $CS^n = D^{n+1}$ (where C means cone) and $\Sigma S^n = S^{n+1}$ (where $\Sigma$ means suspencion)?  It is just the first claim I've met in the textbook and wasn't able to prove.

Comment: Have you studied the quotient topology and quotient maps? If not, that's what you need to do to make these kinds of arguments rigorous. I suggest starting with the quotient topology chapter in Munkres "Topology".

Comment: @Lee Mosher, Yes, I have, it's not a problem. The problem was a quite lot technical details (unlike the answer below I was trying to use coordinate charts and so on but how we can see, it could be done easier by using embeding into $R^n$ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably best to work with the actual definitions for these things.  For example, the cone is $S^n\times I /\sim$, where that equivalence relation is $(x,0)\sim(y,0)$ (in other words, collapse all points at the $(\_,0)$ coordinate to a single point).  It's easy to define a map from $S^n\times I$ to $D^{n+1}$: $(x,t)\rightarrow tx$. Because this is constant on that equivalence class above, it descends to a map from $CS^n\rightarrow D^{n+1}$. [This is the defining property of quotient spaces.]

This map is onto (because the non-quotient version was), and it should be easy to show it's injective. Then the usual compact-Hausdorff stuff shows this is a homeomorphism.

For the suspension, the argument is similar.  This time, you need a map from $S^n\times[-1,1]\rightarrow S^{n+1}$. You can use 
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n),t\rightarrow (\lambda x_1, \ldots, \lambda x_n, t)$$
where $\lambda=\sqrt{1-t^2}$.

Comment: How is $(x,0)\sim (y,0)$ for every $x,y$ an equivalence relation? For it to be an equivalente relation, shouldn't you have $(x,r)\sim(x,r)$ always? This definition only applies to elements who's second component is $1$.